# How to get the size in physical pixels of an Node displayed on the screen?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I want to render an image that will be displayed in in `ImageView`. How do I get the size of the `ImageView` in the screen's physical pixels, regardless of screen scaling? I'm using JavaFX 8.

`view.getWidth()` and `.getHeight()` return values scaled by the screen's DPI. On my high-dpi display, `Screen.getPrimary().getDpi()` returns half of its actual dpi.

Comment: I think `Screen.getPrimary().getOutputScaleX()` and `Screen.getPrimary().getOutputScaleY()` give you the scaling factors. (These were added in JavaFX 9.)

Comment: I'm stuck with Java 8, unfortunately.